# Como converter uma página html em Imagem e fazer o download IE e Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

Preciso converter uma pagina HTML em uma imagem e realizar o download dessa imagem. Consegui para o Chrome e Firefox, mas no IE não funciona de jeito nenhum em nenhuma das versões. No Safári 5 não consegui fazer o download, ao clicar no link abre a imagem no navegador.

Alguém sabe por acaso se ha uma possibilidade de funcionar no IE >=9 pelo menos a partir da versão 9 e Safári mais atual?

**Aviso no IE 11 ao clicar no link Download:** DOM7011: O código nesta página desabilitou o armazenamento em cache anterior e posterior. Para obter mais informações, consulte: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() { 
  html2canvas($("#widget"), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $("#btnSave").click(function(){
     $("#btnSave").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL());
    });
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    }
    .dataset {
      float: left;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .widget {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      line-height: 20px !important;
      margin: 5px;
      vertical-align: top;
      color: #333;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      page-break-after: always;
    }
    .widget .header p {
      padding: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
      max-width: 360px;
    }
    .widget .header .title {
      font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align: middle;
      min-height: 36px;
      padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    }
    .widget .header:hover {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    .widget .header .title.selected {
      border-color: cornflowerblue;
      background-color: #EEF;
    }
    .widget .content {
      padding: 5px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      max-height: 400px;
    }
    .autolayout {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .element {
      width: 360px;
    }
    .compact .content {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .compact .row {
      display: table-row;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .compact .cell {
      display: table-cell;
    }
    .compact .row.selected {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .toolbar {
      display: block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .toolbar .basis {
      min-width: 100px;
    }
    .btn {
      /*min-width: 60px;*/
    }
    .cell.value {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-wrap: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .cell.freq {
      width: 60px;
    }
    .cell.glyph {
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100px;
    }
    .element {} .element table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .element td {
      padding: 0px;
    }
    .element .selectable:hover {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    .element .stat {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      font-weigth: bold;
      color: darkgray;
    }
    .element .bar {
      height: 18px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }
    .bar-both {
      background-color: #0a67a3 !important;
    }
    .bar-fg {
      background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
    }
    .bar-bg {
      background-color: #ddd !important;
    }
    .selected .bar-fg {
      background-color: #FC0;
    }
    .selected .bar-both {
      background-color: #FA0;
    }
    tr.selected {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .crosstab .selectable:hover {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    .crosstab tr.selected {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .crosstab .header p {
      max-width: 600px;
    }
    .crosstab td {
      padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .crosstab td.value {
      min-width: 60px;
      max-width: 240px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .crosstab .cell {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .crosstab th.cell {
      max-width: 120px;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: normal;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 10px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .crosstab .n {
      color: darkgray;
    }
    .fieldlist {} .constraints {
      min-width: 300px;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .constraints table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .sidenote {
      max-width: 300px;
      padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .headnote {
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .info-block {
      /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
      background-color: #eee;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
      /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
    }
    .menu-item {} .menu-item-value {
      text-align: right;
      float: right;
    }
    .gradient-blue {
      background: #b8e1fc;
      /* Old browsers */
      /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
      background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
      /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
      /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
      /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
      /* W3C */
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0);
      /* IE6-8 */
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://hongru.github.io/proj/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/0.3.0/base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
        <div class="header ng-scope">
          <div class="title ng-binding">AGE</div>
          <p class="ng-binding">Patient age, in years</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element ng-scope">
          <div ng-show="hasData()" class="content">
            <table ng-model="table" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
              <colgroup>
                <col/>
                <col width="60x"/>
                <col width="100px"/>
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="cell value">Value</th>
                  <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
                  <th class="cell value"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="0" class="selectable ng-scope">
                <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19" class="ng-scope ng-binding">0 to 19</span>
      </td>

      <td class="cell freq ng-binding">17.2%</td>
      <td class="cell glyph">
        <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
        <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="20" class="selectable ng-scope">
        <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39" class="ng-scope ng-binding">20 to 39</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cell freq ng-binding">18.0%</td>
        <td class="cell glyph">
          <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
      <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="40" class="selectable ng-scope">
        <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59" class="ng-scope ng-binding">40 to 59</span>
        </td>

        <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
        <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
        <td class="cell glyph">
          <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
          <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
      <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="60" class="selectable ng-scope">
        <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79" class="ng-scope ng-binding">60 to 79</span>
        </td>

        <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
        <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
        <td class="cell glyph">
          <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
          <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
      <tr ng-repeat="rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort " ng-click="onSelect(rowKey, $event.shiftKey)" ng-class="{true:'selected'}[isSelected(rowKey)]" data-key="80" class="selectable ng-scope">
        <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99" class="ng-scope ng-binding">80 to 99</span>
        </td>

        <!--<td >{{table.getRowPercent('current', rowKey) | percent}}</td>-->
        <td class="cell freq ng-binding">6.4%</td>
        <td class="cell glyph">
          <!--<div class="bar bar-both" style="width: {{(row.current.pct * 100)||2}}px; " ></div>-->
          <span class="bar bar-both" ng-style="{width: (table.getBothPct(rowKey) | barSize)+'%' }" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-fg" ng-style="{width: (table.getFgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-bg" ng-style="{width: (table.getBgPct(rowKey) | barSize) +'%' }" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: rowKey in table.rowKeys | orderBy:elementRowSort -->
      <tr ng-show="getShowMean()" class="">
        <td class="stat">Mean</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">46.1</td>
      </tr>


      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>


      </div>
      <!-- ngRepeat: field in getChildren(field) -->
      </span>
      <br/>
      <a id="btnSave" download="mypainting.png">Link Download</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esta usando uma versão desatualizado do html2canvas, estamos na versão [0.5](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) que funciona nos seguintes navegadores:

- Firefox 3.5+
- Google Chrome
- Opera 12+ (presto)
- IE9+
- Safari 6+

Note entanto o html2canvas não tira uma foto de verdade, ele na verdade tenta redesenhar os elementos, então coisas como algumas funcionalidades do svg e css não irão funcionar, ou seja existe uma série de coisas ainda pra implementar.

Tenha em mente que a biblioteca é totalmente experimental.

O erro *DOM7011* eu nunca vi no [issues do html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues) então provavelmente é alguma outra coisa que falhou, testei o código e tinha falhas que não fizeram funciona em vários navegadores, outra coisa estranha é que você chamou $.ready e depois $(function) que é a mesma coisa no jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() { 
    });
});
```

Fora que o uso do link estava errado, faça assim:

```
$(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $("#btnSave").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL());
        }
    });
});
```

Porque com `click` pra depois setar o `attr` ele vai tentar fazer o download de algo que não existe, por causa do tempo de execução.

Agora o mais importante, você colocou elementos `block` dentro de `span`, isto é errado, troque o span por div, assim:

```
<div id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
    <div class="header ng-scope">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

### Problema do IE com protocolo DATA

No IE em links ou popup o protocolo data solicita um aplicativo externo, porque de certa forma ele não é reconhecido, então a unica maneira de contornar o problema é colocando o resultado do canvas em uma tag img assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $("#imageSaved").html("");
                $("<img />").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL()).appendTo("#imageSaved");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="imageSaved"></div>
```

E depois terá que clicar com o direito do mouse/rato na imagem e `Salvar como...` (ou `Guardar`).

Isto é devido a uma limitação do IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or attributes.
>   object (images only)
>
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on.

### Alternativa para Internet Explorer 11

No IE11 você pode usar o [`canvas.msToBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465735.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), também adicionei o uso do `createObjectURL` pra IE10, mas não sei se vai funcionar, não tenho o IE10 pra testar aqui, o código ficou assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var URL = !!(window.URL || window.webkitURL || false);
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $("#btnSave").click(function(){
                if (canvas.msToBlob) { //for IE
                    var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'dicomimage.png');
                } else if (URL) {
                    //Talvez funcione no IE10
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+[;]base64,/g, "");
                    var bdata = new Blob([window.atob(data)], {type: "image/png"});
                    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(bdata);
                    this.href = url;

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        url.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    }, 100);
                } else {
                    this.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Atualizei a biblioteca html2canvas versão 0.5, agora esta carregando no IE >9 a imagem dentro da tag <img />, mas ainda não sei como fazer o download da imagem. Ex: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...> como consigo fazer o download da imagem redesenhada?

Comment: @AlmirAntonio é como eu disse é uma limitação do IE por causa do protocolo `data:` você terá que clicar com o direito do mouse em cima da imagem e depois `Salvar como...`, não tem realmente o que fazer.

Comment: @AlmirAntonio editei a resposta e coloquei o link da microsoft que explica esta limitação. Infelizmente não há o que fazer.

Comment: Entendi, já que a solução é clicar com o direito do mouse/rato na imagem e Salvar  como... é possível fazer via javascript? A ideia seria criar uma função que faria esse clique com o botão direito e escolher Salvar imagem, ou viajei muito.

Comment: Então não é possivel controlar o mouse do usuário por javascritp e realmente não vejo nenhuma solução alternativa pra internetexplorer, eu realmente não desgosto do IE, mas realmente esse navegador é bem complicado. Mas acho que achei um fallback com "Flash" vou editar a pergunta amanhã porque tenho que sair, mas parece sim ter uma solução ;)

Comment: @AlmirAntonio foi um pouco dificil mas consegui sem precisar do Flash, agora funciona no IE11, poderia testar?

Comment: eu testei aqui usando o Emulador do IE e funciona no IE10 e 11 com o 'canvas.msToBlob'. Essa parte que vc colocou "//Talvez funcione no IE10" não precisei aqui pro IE10. Ai tentei no IE9,10,11 e nenhum funcionou. No caso do IE10,11 deu esse erro...O objeto não oferece suporte à propriedade ou método 'revokeObjectURL', para entrar no If eu forcei comentando o primeiro.

Comment: @AlmirAntonio foi erro meu no código, vou corrigir, não cheguei a testar no IE9 porque não tenho aqui :/