# Salvar imagem na área de trabalho com html2canvas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html2canvas

Como faço pra salvar a imagem na área de trabalho ou em alguma outra pasta da máquina do usuário ?

Peguei o exemplo muito bom de como gerar a imagem e salvar em uma pasta do servidor aqui: [Tirar print Screen e salvar imagem automaticamente em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17450/tirar-print-screen-e-salvar-imagem-automaticamente-em-c/17480#17480)

Fiz uma adaptação como o exemplo abaixo:

```
$("#btnImprimir").click(function () {

        var target = $('#box-graphs');
        html2canvas(target, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                    $.post('/Exame/Imagem', { 'data': dataUrl }, function (data) {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            alert('Imagem enviada com sucesso');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível controlar a máquina do visitante através do navegador, isto seria uma falha de segurança, pergunte a si mesmo, *você gostaria que um site pudesse controlar as pastas do seu computador?*

Todavia é possível permitir o download automático, claro que cada navegador terá uma limitação, como eu mostrei aqui alguns meios de tentar contornar o problema no IE: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115223/3635

```
$("#btnImprimir").click(function () {
    var NOME_IMAGEM = 'download.png';

    var aLink = document.createElement('a');
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click");

    var target = $('#box-graphs');

    html2canvas(target, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

            //Download no IE11
            if (canvas.msToBlob) {
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, NOME_IMAGEM);

            //Download para navegadores que suportam o atributo download=""
            } else if (typeof a.download !== "undefined") {
                aLink.download = NOME_IMAGEM;
                aLink.href = dataUrl;
                aLink.dispatchEvent(evt);

            //Download para outros navegadores (provavel que não funcione em mobiles)
            } else {
                window.location.href = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+[;]/g, "data:application/octet-stream;");
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Creio que você não conseguirá realizar este procedimento. Uma aplicação web nunca terá acesso a nenhuma informação da máquina local do usuário por segurança, como por exemplo a estrutura de pastas.

Nem mesmo o navegador que está instalado na maquina do usuário não consegue este tipo de informação. O que eu indicaria para você fazer era retornar a `url` do documento que foi gerado no servidor e assim incluir um novo elemento na tela do usuário com o link para download. Neste caso o próprio usuário escolheria onde salvar esta imagem.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!

Answer (score -1):

Você terá quer usar a biblioteca FileSaver.js junto com o html2canvas.js para conseguir salvar o arquivo na máquina do usuário, mas mesmo assim o navegador dará a opção de o usuário escolher o local ao deseja salvar o arquivo.

Der uma olhada na documentação do FileSaver.js que irá resolver seu problema